# Scaling of objective function in optimization problems

Tags: optimization, scale

In a lot of optimization algorithms I have seen that they use a scaling factor to scale the objective function. I dont understand what is the reason behind this. Why do we need scaling of objective function in optimization algorithms? Does it work without scaling. Logically it should work but I am a litte bit confused now.

I hope you can answer me and thank you indeed

Comment: do you have an example of what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Scaling is often used in optimization problems to either:
A) Make better answers look MUCH better (log scaling)
or
B) Make the difference between an OK answer and a slightly better answer come closer together (Quashing functions).

Most algorithms should work on a non-scaled objective function, but will likely work better on the scaled version.

To see the effect I recommend running your meta-heuristic on both versions.

Comment: In Glowwswarm optimization algorithm there is an update rule:  l(t+1) = (1 - rho)l(t) + ghamma*J(x(t));  ghamma is the scaling factor. Here I dont understand why do we need to use scaling

Comment: .How do you mean make a better answer look much better? I cant find any example explaining this issue in a clear way

Comment: Addon - I believe the scaling of gamma in the glow-worm Luciferin update process is to keep the values within the acceptable range of the algorithm.  Otherwise it would be possible to exceed maximal values.  I've never worked with that particular algorithm before - but in the PSO for example, there is a maximal level for velocities.